# AEM 6.2 Dialog - Enable/Disable textfield when checkbox is check/unchecked.

Tags: aem

I am building a fairly simple dialog in Touch UI  (AEM 6.2) that has a check box and a text field. I want to enable/disable the textfield based on whether the checkbox is checked/unchecked. How do I go about this?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery events handlers to achieve this in Touch UI. Add Javascript/jQuery logic to the listeners.js file. This file defines JavaScript logic that defines event handlers for the TOuch UI component. Add the following the code to the JS file at: /apps/touchevents/components/clientlib/listeners.js.(Just for example)

```
(function ($, $document) {
"use strict";
  $document.on("dialog-ready", function() {
    $(window).adaptTo("foundation-ui").alert("Open", "Dialog now open, event [dialog-ready]");
});
})($, $(document));
```

Below are some useful links:

http://aempodcast.com/2016/javascript/simple-touch-ui-dialog-extensions-aem/#.WXD9LYTyuCg

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-touchui-events.html

Comment: You can take reference from http://aemconcepts.blogspot.in/2016/11/show-hide-dialog-fields-based-on.html